# Line passing trough two points

Tags: functions

**Theroem:** Given two points $A$ and $B$ with coordinates $(x_A;y_A)$ and $(x_B;y_B)$ then the equation of the line passing trough both $A$ and $B$ is 
$$y= y_{A/B}+\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\cdot(x-x_{A/B})$$
$$
\text{where} 
\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{y_A-y_B}{x_A-x_B}=\frac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}$$

---

**Demonstration:**

The equation for a generic line in the cartesian plane is $y=mx+c$.

We know that
$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{b}{a}=\frac{y_B-y_a}{x_B-x_A}=\frac{y_A-y_B}{x_A-x_B}$$
[image: img1]

Since $\alpha=\tan^{-1}(\tan\alpha)$
$$\alpha=\tan^{-1} \frac{y_B-y_a}{x_B-x_A}=\tan^{-1}\frac{y_A-y_B}{x_A-x_B}$$
From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020525/formula-for-the-angle-of-a-line-y-mx-as-a-function-of-m) post here we have that $\alpha = \tan^{-1}(m)$ so we have:
$$\alpha = \tan^{-1}(m)=\tan^{-1}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\rightarrow m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \tag {1}$$

If $y = mx+c$ then $c=y-mx$ where $y$ and $x$ are the coordinates of a generic point on the line; so we can rewrite $$c=y_A -\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\cdot x_A=y_B -\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\cdot x_B = y_{A/B} -\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\cdot x_{A/B} \tag 2$$
Finally we have:
$m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \tag {1}$

$c=y_{A/B} -\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\cdot x_{A/B} \tag 2$
And since $y= mx+c$ the final equation is:
$$y=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\cdot x + y_{A/B} -\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\cdot x_{A/B} ; \ y=y_{A/B} + \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\cdot (x-x_{A/B})$$
QED

Is this correct?

---

p.s. I don't now anything about calculus but I noticed that $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ should be the derivative of the function or something...

Comment: I would say, for points 1, 2 of ratios of similar triangles: $\frac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1}=\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}$

Comment: How do you know they are similar?

Answer (score 1):

[image: triangles ABB 'and AMM']

Triangles ABB 'and AMM' are similar $\Rightarrow \frac{y-y1}{y_2-y_1}=\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}$ is the equation of a line through the points A, B. M (x, y) is the generic point of the search line.